# Massive editing to fix typos

Tags: feature-request, edits

On my way towards the [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor) badge I've been fixing quite a lot of typos recently. Some of them are rather obvious, i.e. *desing* to design and *paramter* to parameter.

It has occured to me that an easy way of fixing a number of typos exactly in the same way would be useful. For example, I could ask the site to replace all desing by design, at least, in question titles; get a list of results (proposed changes); and manually accept each of them with a "Confirm change" button.

This would accelerate a process that would be dangerous if done in a totally automated way, but that with an easy manual confirmation step, would add value to the site in a fast way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We don't want edits to be a single typo like that, and we really don't want it make it so easy to fix a single typo without scouring the post to see what else needs fixing first.  If you really want to fix all instances of a typo, search for it.  But look through the post and find other things to correct while you're there.

Comment: Indeed.  Some typos are often an indicator that there are other items that could be cleaned up.

Comment: I find that a post that has one less typo represents an improvement, even if there were other typos.

Comment: Please may I respectfully disagree with this answer? Generally, it is not how Wikipedia works, which works fine. Specifically, I think that editors (at least editors with a certain reputation level) should be allowed to fix typos, perhaps marking them as a typo fix (new checkbox). I do not think it encourages contribution to say "if you want to put in a bit of work to make this better, then you're going to have to put in even more work to be allowed to". It also leaves posts (I've seen several) where there is a single blatant typo but nothing else to fix, so that the typo MUST be left there.